# Can Catboost's verbose be an int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, ipython, catboost

I'm using python's CatBoostClassifier().

Can I change its verbose to an *int*? The output is currently the measured loss functions to stdout, every single iteration, turning this output exhaustively long to analyse.

I'd like to see this output in 50-iterations intervals, like `verbose=50` (verbose=int).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set verbose=int in CatBoost starting from version 0.7